# Radiobuttonlist event not always firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a radiobuttonlist with a selectedindexchanged event that updates a search function.  One of the items is specified in the aspx, and the others are appended databound items.  No matter what I set as the default, that item will not fire the event.  All other items will fire the event.  Also, it seems that after the "dead" item is selected, the event won't fire at all.

How can I track down the error and correct?  Here is current code.

EDIT: Sorry if the short version was misleading.  I wasn't sure what to include.  Here is the whole page.

All aspx:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MSDS/MSDS.master" EnableEventValidation="false"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchMSDS.aspx.cs" Inherits="MSDS_ByDept" Title="NCLWeb - Search MSDS" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="SqlWhereBuilder" Namespace="UNLV.IAP.WebControls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="Server">
    <h2>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server">Search Active MSDS</asp:Label></h2>
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 435px" valign="top">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSearch" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSimpleSearch" runat="server" Width="262px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="96px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdvSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdvSearch_Click" Font-Size="Small">Show Advanced Search</asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlAdvSearch" runat="server" Width="635px" DefaultButton="btnRunAdvSearch">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRunAdvSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnRunAdvSearch_Click" Text="Advanced Search" />
                    <cc1:SqlWhereBuilder ID="SqlWhereBuilder1" runat="server" ClientCodeLocation="../JavaScripts/SqlWhereBuilder.js"
                        FieldsFile="../ConfigFiles/SearchMSDS.config" OperatorListsFile="../ConfigFiles/SearchMSDS.config"
                        ValueEntryFile="../ConfigFiles/SearchMSDS.config">
                    </cc1:SqlWhereBuilder>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </asp:Panel>
                <cc2:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="pnlAdvSearch_CollapsiblePanelExtender" runat="server"
                    CollapseControlID="btnAdvSearch" Collapsed="True" Enabled="True" ExpandControlID="btnAdvSearch"
                    TargetControlID="pnlAdvSearch">
                </cc2:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlStatus" runat="server">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblStatus" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                        AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="DisplayValue"
                        DataValueField="Value" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3" 
                        CausesValidation="True" Visible="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">All</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCLWebConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="getOptionList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="msds_Status" Name="ListName" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upd2">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export Results" 
                            OnClick="btnExport_Click1" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100" DynamicLayout="False">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." style="text-align: center" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProgress" runat="server"></asp:Label></ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridResults" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlMSDS" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridResults_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No matching MSDS Sheets." OnSorted="gridResults_Sorted">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" Visible="false"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ChemicalTitle" HeaderText="ChemicalTitle" SortExpression="ChemicalTitle" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="Manufacturer" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UsageDept" HeaderText="UsageDept" SortExpression="UsageDept" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Health" HeaderText="Health" visible="false" SortExpression="Health" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fire" HeaderText="Fire"  visible="false" SortExpression="Fire" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Reactivity" HeaderText="Reactivity"  visible="false" SortExpression="Reactivity" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUpdated" HeaderText="DateUpdated" SortExpression="DateUpdated" />
                </Columns>
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlMSDS" OnSelected="sqlMSDS_OnSelected" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCLWebConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID]
                                      ,[ChemicalTitle]
                                      ,[Manufacturer]
                                      ,[UsageDept]
                                      ,[Notes]
                                      ,[Health]
                                      ,[Fire]
                                      ,[Reactivity]
                                      ,[DateUpdated]
                                      FROM [msds_Sheets]" OnSelecting="sqlMSDS_Selecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRunAdvSearch" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rblStatus" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

And code-behind:

```
    List<String> safeWords = new List<String>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlStatus.Visible = User.IsInRole("msds_Admin");

    gridResults.DataKeyNames = new String[] { "id" };

    txtSimpleSearch.Focus();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        safeWords.Add("delete");
        safeWords.Add("insert");
        safeWords.Add("update");
        safeWords.Add("set");
        safeWords.Add("exec");
        safeWords.Add("N'");

        sqlMSDS.SelectCommand += " Where status = 0 ";

        Session["Sql"] = sqlMSDS.SelectCommand;

        try
        {
            Session["OriginalSQL"] = sqlMSDS.SelectCommand.Remove(sqlMSDS.SelectCommand.IndexOf("Where"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Session["OriginalSQL"] = sqlMSDS.SelectCommand;
        }
    }
}

protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((Label)UpdateProgress1.FindControl("lblProgress")).Text = "Searching...";

            if (btnSearch.Visible)
            {
                btnSearch_Click(null, null);

                if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "All")
                {
                    sqlMSDS.SelectCommand += " And Status = " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Somehow force the grid to research using no status parameter
                    sqlMSDS.SelectCommand = Session["Sql"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnRunAdvSearch_Click(null, null);

                if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "All")
                {
                    if (sqlMSDS.SelectCommand.Contains("Where"))
                    {
                        sqlMSDS.SelectCommand += " And Status = " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sqlMSDS.SelectCommand += " Where Status = " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Somehow force the grid to research using no status parameter
                    sqlMSDS.SelectCommand = Session["Sql"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your issue is not clear. So you mean it is not doing a PostBack at all or doing in certain cases? Did you set breakpoints in the code-behind and see what's happening? Are there any validation on the page? If yes, see if they are interfering. You can check this by setting CausesValidation="false for your RBL.

Comment: Postback is happening in all cases except when set to default.  No validations on page.

Comment: Weird. i.e. When you Select "All" item, which looks default, correct? Just to be sure you are doing that on Change correct and not when it is already selected? And one other thing I can think of is any javascript code interfering for that particular item. Sorry for guessing but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't postback for one item only.

Comment: @gbs -Yes, when I select "All" in this case.  However I tried changing the default and got the same result with that item.  There isn't any Javascript on the page.  Yes, to test I've been chosing one of the other values, then clicking on the default value, which should fire the selectedindexchanged event.

Comment: Sorry, running out of clues and hard to tell without debugging. May be you can try in a brand new page. And when debugging did you try setting breakpoints in the Page_Load?

Comment: Where in the page cycle are you binding the RadioButtonList and how are you doing it?

Comment: The radiobuttonlist is bound declaratively using an SqlDataSource.

Comment: @MAW, so if you select item 3 it posts back but when you try to select item 1(which was default) after the first post back it doesn't do anything?

Comment: I pasted your exact markup into a new project, did not modify anything except the SQL data source to hook up to a table in one of my DB's, even kept the same return field names, and it works fine.  Are you using VS 2010, .NET 4, and have you tried your posted code in a new project?  Also, what values are being returned from SQL to populate the DDL?  Finally, and most importantly, is the server side event not firing, or is the autopostback not occurring?  Two different problems there.

Comment: @pseudocoder -VS 2008 SP1 .NET 3.5.  When I set a breakpoint within the radiobuttonlist's selectedindex changed property, it does not get hit once I reselect the default.  How can I tell the difference between serverside event and autopostback?

Comment: @MAW74656 by autopostback, I mean the javascript function that causes your web browser to post, thereby causing server-side events to fire.  You can usually tell if the autopostback works on the browser because you will see the page reload momentarily, or more reliably you can breakpoint the `Page.Load` event to see if that fires after your click.

Comment: I'm using updatepanels, but no explicit javascript.

Comment: OK you need to put the UpdatePanel markup in your example then, that changes everything.  See answer regarding this below.

Comment: @MAW set a breakpoint on the `Page_Load`, if you hit that breakpoint when a new item is selected, then autopostback is working. I also copied your code into a new page (hooked to my DB) and had no issues breaking in to `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` for any item I chose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this RadioButtonList specified as AsyncPostBackTrigger for another UpdatePanel? If so, check following link: [CheckedChanged event not firing on a radio button within UpdatePanel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1126914.aspx/1/10?CheckedChanged%20event%20not%20firing%20on%20a%20radio%20button%20within%20UpdatePanel)

I have reproduce that behaviour and fix this with the following script:

```
 $(function () {
        $("input[type='radio']:first", $("#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>")).attr("checked", true);
    });
```

if you can't use the jQuery try this javascript:

```
 window.onload = function () {
        window.document.getElementById("<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>_0").checked = true;
    };


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RadioButtonListDefaultValue", String.Format("window.document.getElementById('{0}_0').checked = true;", RadioButtonList1.ClientID), true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this JQuery?  I haven't been using anything like that on this project.

Comment: @1stein you are assuming he is using `UpdatePanel`?  Or did I miss something?

Comment: Right this only on reason I found the default checked value doesn't fire the OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: @1stein -Just so I understand, your suggesting I don't set a default, then run this JavaScript function on page load?

Comment: Right. Also, if you have controls that can fire non-async postback, you must add that script on the server side in the Page_Load event instead of adding script in page's markup. I have update answer for this situation.

Comment: @1stein -Its weird, but it works.  Can this be modified so I can use one of my databaound items as the default?  I would actually like to try it with value = 0 as the default.

Comment: @1stein -Nevermind, I figured it out, just use `"window.document.getElementById('{0}_1').checked = true;"` and it selects the second option.  I'd really like to know why this happens in the first place though!

Comment: Actually, you have few ways to fix this bug once and then use usual behaviour. The first one is write custom control, inherit it from the RadioButtonList and then use it. The second is to implement adapter for the RadioButtonList contol. The trick is to remove Selected property value and register appropriate javascript. Look solution for the custom control here: http://pastebin.com/UJa6JPVc

Comment: @1stein -Is this a radiobuttonlist bug?  Is Microsoft aware of it?

Comment: Lol no idea why do we have to make such workaround but it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what was happening to me and the fix.

I had a radiobuttonlist that was not in an update panel, but defined as a trigger for an update panel. I had onselectedindexchanged defined as well. Radiobuttonlist had the first listitem attribute selected="true", so it would be selected by default on page load. Then selecting the second listitem worked fine, posting back and updating the update panel.

However, selecting the first item again was not firing onselectedindexchanged event. Using Firefox's awesome Inspect Element utility, I was able to determine that the server was generating the  html element (checked only on the first, default list item). But since the radiobuttonlist was not in the update panel, the checked="checked" attribute for the second item was never getting written to the browser, even though client-side the second radio button visually appeared to be selected. Therefore, when selecting the original item the second time, the onselectedindexchanged was not firing server-side, because the newly selected index was already indicated as selected in the POST event.

You won't see this problem if the list is inside the panel you want to refresh, because the postback causes the browser to receive "new"  elements with the checked="checked" on the newly selected item. The layout of my page made it inconvenient to have these in the same panel, so the fix for me was to put the radiobuttonlist in it's own little update panel. Whichever works for you, the answer is to make sure the radiobuttonlist is in SOME update panel, so the checked attribute can be sent to the browser for each item when selected.

Answer (score 0):

As user user2965308 said, if the RadioButtonList is inside of the UpdatePanel this issue doesn't happen.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/118042/RadioButtonList-Postback-issue-when-selected-by-co
"Get it inside an update panel, with property "ChildrenAsTriggers" on true. This solve the issue for me."

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">All</asp:ListItem>
```

Clicking "All" doesn't change the selected index since that item was already selected, so the event does not fire.  Picking any other option changes the selected option and causes the event to fire.  I believe your goal is to display results for all statuses when you click on "All".  You should do one of the following:

- Display those results when the page initially loads since "All" is already selected.
- Add a "Search" button that initiates the post-back instead of using the radio button's AutoPostBack.
- Replace the RadioButtonList with a DropDownList, and give it two initial ListItems: "Pick a Status" - whose value is an empty string, and "All" whose value is "All".  The "Pick a Status" dummy entry would look less out of place in a DropDownList than in a RadioButtonList.

Of the options listed above, I would personally prefer the "Search" button, because AutoPostBack annoys me as a user.  I hate AutoPostBack DropDownLists that make the web page go bonkers when I accidentally use my mouse wheel when the list has focus.

Comment: I do have a search button, but I want the search results to autoupdate when the radio buttons are changed.  Also, I believe your not quite following my problem: When I select another option, then GO BACK to the default option, this is where I don't get the event.

Comment: Also, I'd really like to get the radiobuttonlist working, as it makes sense visually and I like that design.  I'm not really interested in replacing the radiobuttonlist, especially because it should be able to do this.