# updatePanel not refreshing on radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, updatepanel

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist when the radio button is clicked. No problem the first time, but the second time I go the initial one it does not work. Meaning that Quote works on load, apply works when clicked, but when going back to quote the ddl does not get refreshed. Any ideas? Please be gentle, new to this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelToggle" runat="server" UpdateMode="always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOn" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle" Text="Quote" OnCheckedChanged="radioOn_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOff" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle" Text="Apply" OnCheckedChanged="radioOff_CheckedChanged" />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radioOn" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radioOff" />

    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                loadQuoteURLs();
            }
        }

        protected void radioOn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
                loadQuoteURLs();
        }

        protected void radioOff_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadApplyURLs();
        }

        protected void loadApplyURLs()
        {

            DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Apply");

        }

        protected void loadQuoteURLs()
        {

            DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Quote");

        }
```

Comment: Probably this is not your problem, but: The way you coded you don't need the Triggers and set UpdateMode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radiobuttonlist event not always firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098432/radiobuttonlist-event-not-always-firing)

Comment: I will try 2 thinks in your case to see what works. First remove the trigger because the radio buttons are all ready inside the update panel, and if this is not work, try to update it manual by using the `UpdatePanelId.Update();`. Also you can try to remove the UpdatePanel to see if you have any other error and is not the update panel the problem

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and works fine. Anyway, you don't need to specify `UpdateMode="always"` and set the `AsyncPostBackTriggers` in this case:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelToggle" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOn" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle"
            Text="Quote" OnCheckedChanged="radioOn_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOff" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle"
            Text="Apply" OnCheckedChanged="radioOff_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```