# Setting selected value of RadioButtonList does not work as expected

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a div, which is shown or hidden on the basis of some condition. In that `Div` I have some code as below

```
<div id="addPopUp" runat="server" style="padding: 30px; height: auto; width: 450px;
    overflow: hidden; display: none; background-color: White; border: 1px solid black;">
    <table width="500px;">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="width: 27%;">
                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel" />
                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel1Id" />
                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel2Id" />
                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfLevel3Id" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" align="left" class="topics">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%;">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnMode" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="mylist"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rtbnMode_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Add">Add Link</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Edit">Edit Link</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" align="left" class="topics">
                <strong>Link Name :</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLinkName" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="topics">
                <strong>Url :</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUrl" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="topics">
                <strong>Position :</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosition" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="topics">
                <strong>Show on same page :</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 80%;">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSamePage" runat="server" Checked="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="topics" align="left">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="sfCustomButton" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Hide Link" CssClass="sfCustomButton"
                    Visible="false" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" class="sfCustomButton" onclick="hide()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

out of which **Main Code** comes here

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnMode" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="mylist"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rtbnMode_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Add">Add Link</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Edit">Edit Link</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Here is some `Javascript` code:

```
function showPopUp(Level, Level1Id, Level2Id, Level3Id, id) {
        var radAddEdit = document.getElementById('<%=rbtnMode.ClientID %>');
        var radio = radAddEdit.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
            if (radio[i].value == 'Add') {
                radio[i].checked = true;
            }           
        }     
        document.getElementById("txtLinkName").value = '';
        document.getElementById("txtUrl").value = '';
        document.getElementById("txtPosition").value = '';
        document.getElementById("chkSamePage").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("hfLevel").value = Level;
        document.getElementById("hfLevel1Id").value = Level1Id;
        document.getElementById("hfLevel2Id").value = Level2Id;
        document.getElementById("hfLevel3Id").value = Level3Id;
        document.getElementById("hfEditableId").value = id;
        Popup.showModal('addPopUp', null, null, { 'screenColor': '#cccccc', 'screenOpacity': .6 });
    }
    function hide() {       
        Popup.hide('addPopUp');  
    }
    // function BindEvents() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var hf = document.getElementById("hfShow");
        if (hf.value == "1") {
            Popup.showModal('addPopUp', null, null, { 'screenColor': '#cccccc', 'screenOpacity': .6 });
        }
    });
```

Function `ShowPopUp` is called on a link to show `Div` and resetting it values.
`Hide` is called from `btnCalcel` to hide Div.
`document.ready()` is called to show Div on some condition.

**Code Behind**

```
 protected void rtbnMode_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbtnMode.SelectedValue == "Edit")
            {
                CatalystEntities context = new CatalystEntities();
                btnHide.Visible = true;
                btnSave.Visible = false;
                hfShow.Value = "1";
                string editValue = hfEditableId.Value;
                string levelNumber = editValue.Substring(0, 6);
                long id = Convert.ToInt64(editValue.Substring(6));
                if (levelNumber.Contains("1"))
                {
                    var linkInfo = context.Navigation_level1.
                        Where(i => i.LinkID == id)
                        .Select(i => new
                        {
                            i.LinkName,
                            i.Position,
                            i.Url
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtLinkName.Text = linkInfo.LinkName;
                    txtPosition.Text = linkInfo.Position.ToString();
                    txtUrl.Text = linkInfo.Url;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnSave.Visible = true;
                btnHide.Visible = false;
                hfShow.Value = "1";
                txtLinkName.Text = String.Empty;
                txtPosition.Text = String.Empty;
                txtUrl.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
```

**PROBLEM**

when I open div, go to `Edit` radio, it works fine. But when I click on `btnHide` **(Remember, current selection is EDIT radio button)** and click on other link. `ShowPopUp()` get called and it resets all controls, **BUT** when I click on `EDIT` `Radio` it do not postback, I click on `ADD Radio`, it does, Now if I click on EDIT, it does.

Means, if popup is hidden with selected value `Edit` it doesnot postback for first time when I select Edit radio.
Please ask me if its unclear.
Thanks

Comment: That's a whole lot of code to go through. Nobody has so much time to sift through all this code. IT would be great if you can pinpoint only the buggy part and paste that or produce this in a testing environment like Jsfiddle

Comment: I have written **Main Code** there, but in case, some of you find it incomplete so I pasted all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider setting the **AutoPostBack** property of the control to **false** through the properties window or C#.

Comment: It should always postback dude

Answer (score 0):

There are already post like yours, here is one with the same issue.
[Radiobuttonlist event not always firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098432/radiobuttonlist-event-not-always-firing)

The reason for the difference in actual vs. expected behavior is most likely you have not wrapped your div that has the ID "addPopUp" in an update panel. You can view an example of that below with example panel ID's. Alternativly you could also wrap just your radio button list with an update panel and not include the other controls in the update panel.

Read the documentation on update panels from microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8#introduction).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="addPopUpUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="addPopUpPanel" runat="server">
        <div id="addPopUp" runat="server" style="...">
              <!-- addPopUp contents -->
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32676154)

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut Revisited my answer and gave the most likely issue/fix instead of just the link